# Changing background of embedded iframe to another color or transparent

Tags: html, iframe

I'm embedding an iframe onto Squarespace and trying to change the color of the background of the iframe to match the background of my website (#F6F3EA) but it's not working. I got the embed code from the calendar site I'm trying to embed from.

Below is my embedded code in which I've added style="background-color: #F6F3EA;". The original embed code does not include this. I also want to see if I can make the background of the iframe transparent. When I upload the embed code onto my site the default background color is white.

```
<iframe style="background-color: #F6F3EA;" src="https://testorg1.churchcenter.com/calendar?embed=true&view=list&allowFiltering=true" style="width: 100%; height: 560px;" class="planning-center-calender-embed" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, directly modifying the style of content inside an iframe from the outside is restricted due to the browser's [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
However, it is possible if it's the same domain. It's also possible if the owner of the iframe content provides options for doing so.